# Woocommerce: Specific Product Checkout Shortcode

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, shortcode

Can I get a Specific Product Checkout Shortcode that can be used on any page?

Comment: Do you have any example of your requirement (Website link)?

Comment: What do you mean by a specific Product **Checkout** Shortcode? What does **Checkout** mean here? Thanks

Comment: It is simple. I went to access the checkout page of a certain element from a landing page not from it single product page

Comment: WooCommerce: a Specific Product Checkout Shortcode that can be used on any page like this -> https://rudrastyh.com/plugins/woocommerce-product-checkout-shortcode

Comment: Thank you :) I will check this plugin!